# Padding sequences of 2D elements in keras

Tags: keras, lstm, padding, masking

I have a set of samples, each being a sequence of a set of attributes (for example a sample can comprise of 10 sequences each having 5 attributes). The number of attributes is always fixed, but the number of sequences (which are timestamps) can vary from sample to sample. I want to use this sample set for training an LSTM network in Keras for a classification problem and therefore I should pad the input size for all batch samples to be the same. But the `pad_sequences` processor in keras gets a fixed number of sequences with variable attributes and pad the missing attributes in each sequence, while I need to add more sequences of a fixed attribute length to each sample. So I think I can not use it and therefore I padded my samples separately and made a unified datset and then fed my network with it. But is there a shortcut with Keras functions to do this?

Also I heard about masking the padded input data during learning but I am not sure if I really need it as my classifier assigns one class label after processing the whole sample sequence. do I need it? And if yes, could you please help me with a simple example on how to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, the [documentation](https://keras.io/preprocessing/sequence/#pad_sequences) is quite missleading, but `pad_sequences` does exactly what you want. For example, this code

```
length3 = np.random.uniform(0, 1, size=(3,2))
length4 = np.random.uniform(0, 1, size=(4,2))
pad_sequences([length3, length4], dtype='float32', padding='post')
```

results in

```
[[[0.0385175  0.4333343 ]
  [0.332416   0.16542904]
  [0.69798684 0.45242336]
  [0.         0.        ]]

 [[0.6518417  0.87938637]
  [0.1491589  0.44784057]
  [0.27607143 0.02688376]
  [0.34607577 0.3605469 ]]]
```

So, here we have two sequences of different lengths, each timestep having two features, and the result is one numpy array where the shorter of the two sequences got padded with zeros.

Regarding your other question: Masking is a tricky topic, in my experience. But LSTMs should be fine with it. Just use a [`Masking()`](https://keras.io/layers/core/#masking) layer as your very first one. By default, it will make the LSTMs ignore all zeros, so in you case exactly the ones you added via padding. But you can use any value for masking, just as you can use any value for padding. If possible, choose a value that does not occur in your dataset.

If you don't use masking, that will yield the danger that your LSTM learns that the padded values do have some meaning while in reality they don't.

For example, if during training you feed in the the sequence

```
[[1,2],
 [2,1],
 [0,0],
 [0,0],
 [0,0]]
```

and later on the trained network you only feed in

```
[[1,2],
 [2,1]]
```

You could get unexpected results (not necessarily, though). Masking avoids that by excluding the masked value from training.

Comment: One more question: When I define my model I should specify the input shape in the Input layer of LSTM (which includes both sequence length and number of attributes). How can I make it variable without redefining the model on each batch?

Comment: @Shahriar49 just put `None` for that dimension

Comment: I tried some landcover classification simulations on my sample data (a series of Landsat imagery sequences with 6 attributes per observation) with some small to medium sized LSTM networks, and I tried both pre- and post-padding and enabling/disabling masking. I found that post-padding occasionally surpasses pre-padding in output accuracy, and more surprisingly, no-masking is sometimes better than masking (not the reverse). Do you have any comment?

Comment: @Shahriar49 that would be, indeed, surprising. How big is your data set? If too small, this could be just a coincident. Also, what exactly do you mean by "output accuracy"? Don't compare the accuracies achieved in training! They have no meaning at all! Make sure you test your trained model against some sufficiently large test data set (it must not have been touched during training in any way!). Make sure all different models are trained on the same data and tested on the same data. Only then the test-accuracy does have some meaning and you can compare them.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes I looked at testing accuracies (and the testing data was completely separate from training) but the test data size was on the order of ten thousand sequences, that is not very big. I will try to increase the test data size and wee how it goes. But should I have big train data or test data to have a correct comparison? I think the training data size is more important because masking is going to affect the trained classifier.

Comment: Also I faced a problem that prohibits me to use masking in my next trials on my Nvidia GPU: LSTM CuDNN doesn't support masking :(

Comment: Sorry I have another problem as well! I can apply pad_sequences when I feed my model with numpy arrays as I have access to whole data, but how can I do it when I feed my model through dataset API? In dataset API my processing is done on single example basis (parse_single_example) and I don't know how to process a batch as I don't have access to it (the data generator itself is passed to the model.fit() function and it will generates batches and feed the network with it automatically).

Comment: @Shahriar49 sorry, but this goes way beyond what could easily be clarified in a comment. I'd suggest you open separate questions for all of this. Regarding LSTM on GPU: that is one of the "tricky" things of masking.  It simply isn't supported for all layers that we wish :(

Comment: You are right! Sorry for any inconvenience and thanks for your continued attention. Actually I created another post for my last question a few minutes ago.